# Attachments mandatory for selected choice column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, attachments, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint list for leave request.

I have a column "Type Of Leave" as a choice column. I have enabled attachments already for all the forms we create. But can we make a condition that "Attachments" are mandatory if "Type Of Leave" selected is "Medical Leave, Hospitalization Leave or NS/ICT"?

Any help or guidance on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint OOTB settings to make the attachments field mandatory based on another field on list form.

You have to customize the list form using Power Apps to achieve this requirements.

You can check if there are any attachments added when particular option is selected in choice column before submitting the list for using Power Apps formulas.

For more information, check this threads:

1. [PowerApps attachment control how to check if any attachments have been made](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/PowerApps-attachment-control-how-to-check-if-any-attachments/td-p/238119)

You can use formula like below on `DisplayMode` property of Submit button:

```
If( 
    (ddControlName.Selected.Value = "Medical Leave" || ddControlName.Selected.Value = "Hospitalization Leave" || ddControlName.Selected.Value = "NS/ICT") && CountRows(AttachmentsControlName.Attachments) < 1 ,
    DisplayMode.Disabled,
    DisplayMode.Edit
)
```

Comment: Hi @Nik, did you try this? Is it working for you?